# how to bind data from entityframework to datagrid?

Tags: c#, wpf, linq, entity-framework, data-binding

I have 2 tables `Customer` and `Order` customer id is a primary key and it has foriegn key relationship with order key. so i want to display customers in datagrid and orderd in RowDetailsTemplate which consists of another datagrid.

Below is the XAML

```
   <Grid>
        <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="True" Name="dataGrid1">
            <DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Order}" AutoGenerateColumns="True"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
```

In the codebehind i write the following code

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        SampleDBEntities1 context = new SampleDBEntities1();
        dataGrid1.ItemsSource = context.Customers.ToList();           
    }
```

Here i am unable to bind the inner datagrid.

Below is the Context class

```
public partial class SampleDBEntities1 : DbContext
{
    public SampleDBEntities1()
        : base("name=SampleDBEntities1")
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
    }

    public DbSet<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Order> Orders { get; set; }
}
```

Below are Entityframework generated classes for customer and order

```
public partial class Customer
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }

    public virtual Order Order { get; set; }
}

public partial class Order
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Number { get; set; }

    public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I cannot see you binding your View to ViewModel. Say like, in the MainWindow constructor add this line - this.DataContext = new MyViewModel(). Probably this would be the thing that you are missing out.

Comment: First Put a breakpoint on "context.Customers.ToList()" and see whether you are getting values or not. If you are getting values then use snoop and check why your values are not loading inside the Datagrids.

Answer (score 4):

You need to tell Entity Framework to eager-load the orders, otherwise it won't load them...

```
dataGrid1.ItemsSource = context.Customers.Include("Order").ToList();
```

Or

```
dataGrid1.ItemsSource = context.Customers.Include(c => c.Order).ToList();
```

(Need to add `using System.Data.Entity;`)

It should also work if removed the `.ToList()`, but it would lazy-load orders for each customer and you'd end up with a Select(n+1) problem.

Comment: Can you save the list to a variable first? `var customers = context.Customers.Include(c => c.Order).ToList();` Then add a breakpoint and inspect the customers to see if it's populated properly? Thanks.

Comment: but i want the order list in inner grid not in outer grid